# Migrating .NET & SQL Server database application to a new computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a C# application which connects to a SQL Server database. Everything works well(select, insert, update, delete, etc.). I decided to take my application, database files to a new computer. I knew before that it wouldn't work. I made changes to my application, tried connection string for attached database file, but no luck. It seems I need database driver. But it's not the end. I need to set up database parameters(logins, instance, etc.).
**Do I need to install SQL Server**(I think it's very bad practice) **or is it possible to do it with installer programs?** Any thoughts, links would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's a small/medium load program with no much SQL features in (and I think it is), I recommend you to use SQL CE (Compact Edition).
it will be just a DLL that will be included in your program, and it has the driver required to connect to your database, **with no other dependencies**.

introduction to SQL CE and VS2010 SP1: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

just make sure that you have VisualStudio 2010 with SP1 installed before installing SQL CE.

**SQL CE Download link**: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=212219

from ScottGu's blog:

> SQL CE does not require you to run a setup or install a database
>   server in order to use it.  You can simply copy the SQL CE binaries
>   into the \bin directory of your ASP.NET application, and then your web
>   application can use it as a database engine.  No setup or extra
>   security permissions are required for it to run. You do not need to
>   have an administrator account on the machine. Just copy your web
>   application onto any server and it will work. This is true even of
>   medium-trust applications running in a web hosting environment.
>
> SQL CE runs in-memory within your ASP.NET application and will
>   start-up when you first access a SQL CE database, and will
>   automatically shutdown when your application is unloaded.  SQL CE
>   databases are stored as files that live within the \App_Data folder of
>   your ASP.NET Applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to a local SQL Server database, then yes you need to install SQL server.

You also need the database that you will connect to.

In the connection string you have a user, this user must be defined and have the required access. This is both the sql login to the server and the access to the database.